# Consolidating data from multiple rows into a single varchar(max) field, Is there an alternative to a cursor and .WRITE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in a source table that looks like the below.  This is basically a narrative field that has been split into 47 character chunks.  There is a convention in the data that if the user input a newline, it is replaced with the ` character and that ends that line.

```
CREATE TABLE narrdata (parentindex integer, linenum integer, linetext varchar(48))
```

I want to consolidate the data from individual lines into one varchar(max) field.
The way I've done it before was using a cursor and .WRITE like this.
I'm wondering if there is another way to do this without .WRITE.

```
CREATE TABLE #target_table (myindex integer, narrative varchar(max))

/* some code here to initialize rows in target_table - so assume it already has a row */

DECLARE @item                   integer
DECLARE @line                   integer
DECLARE @chunk                  varchar(54)
DECLARE @crlf                   bit
DECLARE @crlf_last              bit
DECLARE @item_last              integer

DECLARE cur_narr CURSOR FOR
SELECT
   parentindex,
   linenum,
   CASE
      WHEN linetext IS NOT NULL THEN
         CASE
            WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(linetext), 1) = '`' THEN
               SUBSTRING(linetext, 1, LEN(linetext) - 1) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            ELSE
               RTRIM(linetext)
         END
      ELSE ''
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN linetext IS NOT NULL THEN
         CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(linetext), 1) = '`' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ELSE 0
   END
FROM narrdata
WHERE parentindex IN ( /* some condition here */ )
ORDER BY parentindex, linenum

SET @item_last = -1
SET @crlf_last = 1

OPEN cur_narr

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_narr
INTO @item, @line, @chunk, @crlf

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN

   IF @item <> @item_last
      BEGIN

      SET @crlf_last = 1
      SET @item_last = @item

      END

   IF @crlf_last = 0
      SET @chunk = ' ' + @chunk

   UPDATE #target_table
   SET narrative .WRITE(@chunk, NULL, 0)
   WHERE myindex = @item

   SET @crlf_last = @crlf

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_narr
   INTO @item, @line, @chunk, @crlf

   END

CLOSE cur_narr
DEALLOCATE cur_narr


INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 1, 'This is a narrative which should be separated')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 2, 'into several lines in the source data.  I have')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 3, 'no idea which line this part will be in.  This')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 4, 'however should be before a newline.`')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 5, 'A new line just started here.`')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 6, 'Another new line here.  Then some blank lines.`')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 7, '`')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 8, '`')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 9, 'How about this now?  Is this enough sample')
INSERT INTO narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 10, 'data.')
```

Expected Result

```html
<pre>
This is a narrative which should be separated into several lines in the source data.  I have no idea which line this part will be in.  This however should be before a newline.
A new line just started here.
Another new line here.  Then some blank lines.


How about this now?  Is this enough sample data.
</pre>
```

Here is an example you can run for yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE #narrdata (parentindex integer, linenum integer, linetext varchar(48))

INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 1, 'This is a narrative which should be separated')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 2, 'into several lines in the source data.  I have')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 3, 'no idea which line this part will be in.  This')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 4, 'however should be before a newline.`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 5, 'A new line just started here.`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 6, 'Another new line here.  Then some blank lines.`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 7, '`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 8, '`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 9, 'How about this now?  Is this enough sample')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 10, 'data.')

INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 1, 'This is a narrative which should be separated')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 2, 'into several lines in the source data.  I have')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 3, 'no idea which line this part will be in.  This')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 4, 'however should be before a newline.`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 5, 'A new line just started here.`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 6, 'Another new line here.  Then some blank lines.`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 7, '`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 8, '`')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 9, 'How about this now?  Is this enough sample')
INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37792, 10, 'data.')

INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37793, 1, 'A simple line example.')

CREATE TABLE #target_table (myindex integer, narrative varchar(max))

INSERT INTO #target_table (myindex, narrative)
SELECT DISTINCT parentindex, ''
FROM #narrdata

DECLARE @item                   integer
DECLARE @line                   integer
DECLARE @chunk                  varchar(54)
DECLARE @crlf                   bit
DECLARE @crlf_last              bit
DECLARE @item_last              integer

DECLARE cur_narr CURSOR FOR
SELECT
   parentindex,
   linenum,
   CASE
      WHEN linetext IS NOT NULL THEN
         CASE
            WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(linetext), 1) = '`' THEN
               SUBSTRING(linetext, 1, LEN(linetext) - 1) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            ELSE
               RTRIM(linetext)
         END
      ELSE ''
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN linetext IS NOT NULL THEN
         CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(linetext), 1) = '`' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ELSE 0
   END
FROM #narrdata
ORDER BY parentindex, linenum

SET @item_last = -1
SET @crlf_last = 1

OPEN cur_narr

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_narr
INTO @item, @line, @chunk, @crlf

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN

   IF @item <> @item_last
      BEGIN

      SET @crlf_last = 1
      SET @item_last = @item

      END

   IF @crlf_last = 0
      SET @chunk = ' ' + @chunk

   UPDATE #target_table
   SET narrative .WRITE(@chunk, NULL, 0)
   WHERE myindex = @item

   SET @crlf_last = @crlf

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_narr
   INTO @item, @line, @chunk, @crlf

   END

CLOSE cur_narr
DEALLOCATE cur_narr

SELECT * FROM #target_table

DROP TABLE #target_table
DROP TABLE #narrdata
```

Comment: Your SQL Server version and some sample source data would help.

Comment: There are very few times you need a `CURSOR`. I could probably count them on my fingers that you are forced to use one. I doubt what you're trying to achieve (what ever is it) *requires* a `CURSOR` even if it can be achieved with one. Sample data and expected results will greatly help us show you an alternatetive method.

Comment: I think you could try a recursive CTE.

Comment: If the OP can use a non-recursive method that would be even better, @avery_larry .

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Larnu You make me feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: sample data inserts added, feel free to duplicate with a different index for more examples.

Comment: Both a `CURSOR` and rCTE are recursive, @avery_larry , something that RDBMS don't excel at. If the OP can achieve what they want with a non-iterative task, it'll be far more performant.

Comment: Check the `string_agg` function. I think this is what you want.

Comment: BUt what about your expected results, and the version of SQLServer, @WillRickards ?

Comment: sql server 2014 is the current version installed, I've added the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out for SQL Server 2014.

```
    Create table #narrdata (parentindex int, linenum int, linetext nvarchar(max))

    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 1, 'This is a narrative which should be separated')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 2, 'into several lines in the source data.  I have')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 3, 'no idea which line this part will be in.  This')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 4, 'however should be before a newline.`')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 5, 'A new line just started here.`')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 6, 'Another new line here.  Then some blank lines.`')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 7, '`')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 8, '`')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 9, 'How about this now?  Is this enough sample')
    INSERT INTO #narrdata (parentindex, linenum, linetext) VALUES (37791, 10, 'data.')

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' '+ inr.linetext
                FROM #narrdata inr
               WHERE inr.parentindex = nr.parentindex
               ORDER BY inr.linenum
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
  FROM #narrdata nr
 GROUP BY nr.parentindex
```

Comment: This isn't in the right order.  I get :
A new line just started here.`Another new line here.  Then some blank lines.`data.How about this now?  Is this enough samplehowever should be before a newline.`into several lines in the source data.  I haveno idea which line this part will be in.  ThisThis is a narrative which should be separated

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you

```
INSERT INTO narrdata2 (originalparentindex, linetext) 

SELECT parentindex, STUFF(
                        (

SELECT ' ' + CASE WHEN z.linetext = '`' THEN NULL ELSE z.linetext END FROM narrdata z
WHERE z.parentindex = y.parentindex
ORDER BY z.linenum
FOR xml path('')
)
                        , 1
                        , 1
                        , '') FROM narrdata y GROUP BY parentindex
```

I've called the new table `narrdata2` with the following structure, hope it helps!

```
CREATE TABLE narrdata2 (parentindex INT, originalparentindex INT, linetext VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answers, this seems to work.  I switched the handling of added spacing to the end.  And I removed the seemingly extraneous STUFF call which was just removing the first character, I think. This leaves the last line with an extra space character but that's okay.  I added in the REPLACE call to replace the tick marks with CRLF.  The , TYPE.value thing doesn't seem to be required as when I tested with lengths exceeding 8000 it seemed to work.  I should probably look up the max length of the xml data type.  There seems to be an implicit type conversion happening here with or without the REPLACE call.  I'd like to understand that more.

I've used FOR XML PATH before for something similar, though with actual XML, I just didn't consider it.  I'm open to other answers that don't involve FOR XML.

```
SELECT 
   parentindex,                  
    REPLACE( (SELECT z.linetext + CASE WHEN RIGHT(z.linetext, 1) = '`' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END FROM #narrdata z WHERE z.parentindex = y.parentindex ORDER BY z.linenum FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'), '`', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
FROM #narrdata y
GROUP BY parentindex
```

Answer (score 1):

In your request for additional answers not using XML, please see the below using T-SQL loops.

Not sure if it is more efficient but it is certainly more fun. :)

```
CREATE TABLE #target_table
(
    myindex INT, 
    narrative VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @loop INT = 1
DECLARE @lineloop INT = 0

DECLARE @maxloop INT

-- find the max parent index
SET @maxloop = (SELECT MAX(maxloop.parentindex) FROM narrdata maxloop)

DECLARE @maxlineloop INT

-- loop through the parent indexes
WHILE @loop <= @maxloop
    BEGIN
    -- find the max linenum for that the current parent index
    SET @maxlineloop = (SELECT MAX(lineloop.linenum) FROM narrdata lineloop WHERE lineloop.parentindex = @loop)

    -- loop through the linenums for the current parent index
    WHILE @lineloop <= @maxlineloop
        BEGIN
        SET @output = (SELECT ISNULL(@output+' ','') + z.linetext 
        FROM narrdata z
        WHERE z.parentindex = @loop AND z.linenum = @lineloop)
        --Strip out the line breaks chars (plus the additional space before it)
        SET @output = REPLACE(@output,' `','')
        -- add one to the linenum
        SET @lineloop += 1
        END
    -- INSERT THE row into the temp table
    INSERT INTO #target_table (myindex, narrative) VALUES (@loop, @output)
    -- Set the linenum back to 0
    SET @lineloop = 0
    --add 1 to the parentindex loop
    SET @loop += 1
    END

-- Present the results
SELECT * FROM #target_table

-- Drop the temp table
DROP TABLE #target_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another technique but this seems to work only on one index at a time.  Is there a way to adapt this to work on the whole table, aside from the obvious loop and cursor?

```
DECLARE @narrative varchar(max)
SELECT @narrative = COALESCE(@narrative + CASE WHEN RIGHT(@narrative, 1) = '`' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END, '') + linetext
FROM #narrdata
WHERE parentindex = 37791
ORDER BY linenum

SELECT REPLACE( @narrative, '`', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) )
```