# Query to join multiple rows into a single row/column without FOR XML - EDIT With FOR XML

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a fairly complex query which I am trying to put together.  I have 2 tables, tblSMS and tblSMSSent, which contain data for SMS messages sent and received over an API.  I need to write a query which gives me every message sent combined with each response for that message.  I have tried doing this using LiNQ but my second query to receive messages for each sent message is returning nothing.

Here is my initial query to retrieve each message that has been sent out:

```
var query = "Select top({0}) * from (" +
"   SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY[date] desc) " +
"   AS RowNum, RTRIM(phone) as phone, [date], " +
"   RTRIM(LEFT(result,50)) as result, RTRIM(debtor) as debtor, " +
"   RTRIM(sms) as OrigBody, RTRIM([user]) as [user], " +
"   RTRIM(MessageId) as MessageId FROM tblSMSSent " +
"   where RTRIM([user]) = '{2}' " +
") AS tbl WHERE tbl.RowNum > {1} "
```

This query returns the data correctly.
When I run the query with a join, such as

```
Select top{0} * from ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY[date] desc)  
    AS RowNum, RTRIM(phone) as phone, [date],  
RTRIM(LEFT(result,50)) as result, RTRIM(debtor) as debtor,  
    RTRIM(sms) as OrigBody, MessageBody, RTRIM([user]) as [user],  
    RTRIM(MessageId) as MessageId FROM tblSMSSent  
    right join tblSMS on messageId=outgoingmessageId
    where RTRIM([user]) = '{2}'  
) AS tbl WHERE tbl.RowNum > {1}
```

It returns multiple rows for every MessageBody corresponding to that MessageId.  What I need is for MessageBody to contain every message from tblSMS in a single row, delimited in some manner.

This is some sample data which I am getting:

[image: Current Sample Data]

This is the data which I need:
[image: Desired Sample Data]

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to accomplish this with LiNQ as I stated above but that is not a path I want to take, preferring to keep it into a single query if possible.  As I am using an older version of SQL server commands such as For XMLare not available to aid in data manipulation.

Since I am looking to make this complete, I am sending this response data back to the client to display in HTML.  How can I put a line break between the concatenated results?

What are my options?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected resultset.

Comment: Look at the images

Comment: Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600112/consolidating-data-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-varcharmax-field-is-there/61601337#61601337

Comment: My version of SQL server doesn't support the FOR XML functions.  Like I mentioned in question it's an older version of SQL Server, which is why I have posted the question here.

Comment: @Geoff I think I can offer you a solution on this, could you provide me a schema for these two tables please?

Comment: @Simon I figured it out Simon.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I found a solution gleaned from https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Converting%20row%20values%20in%20a%20table%20to%20a%20single%20concatenated%20string.aspx.

What I have done is added in another SubQuery.  After some research I found I was able to use For XML but some of the advanced XML functions are unavailable.

Here is my final query:

```
Select  * from ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY[date] desc)  
    AS RowNum, RTRIM(phone) as phone, [date],  
    RTRIM(LEFT(result,50)) as result, RTRIM(debtor) as debtor,  
    RTRIM(sms) as OrigBody,  RTRIM([user]) as [user],  
    RTRIM(MessageId) as MessageId ,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT '^' + MessageBody
            FROM tblSMS 
            WHERE outgoingMessageId=MessageId
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')) AS MessageText

    FROM tblSMSSent  
    where RTRIM([user]) = 'userName'  and MessageId<>0
) AS tbl WHERE tbl.RowNum > 0
```

This gives me the desired result set delimited by '^', although I can change the delimiter.

FOR XML was introduced in SQL Server 2005, which is what I am using.  I had understood that it was a 2010 innovation but when attempting it on another query I was using other functions which my Server didn't understand.

Thank you [user25407](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3467084/user25407) for your help on this.